# Should I check result of sqlite-net update / insert / delete? (error handling best practice)

Tags: c#, sqlite, error-handling, exception

I'm starting to use SQLite-net and I'm a bit confused about error handling.

Insert / update / delete operations return an int, which is "the number of rows" inserted / updated / deleted.

If I insert 1 element, should I check if the result is 1? Is it the proper way of handling errors?
Or is catching SQLiteException enough (or even required)?

Generaly speaking, what is a good error handling strategy for this library?

Thanks

Comment: The return value does not indicate errors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, when I update 1 line, I can disregard the result. The only important thing to handle errors is to catch SQLiteException. Am I right?